# How to filter MyEvent({ },{ }) to retrieve only the latest transaction in the array?

Tags: web3js, dapps, events

My code:

```
 instance.MyEvent({}, {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'}).watch(function(error, event) {
 if (!error) {
   console.log(event); 
$('#events').html(event.transactionHash);      

 } else {
   console.error(error);
 }
}).get(function(error, events) {
 if (!error) {
    console.log(events);
  } else {
    console.error(error);
  }
})
```

With that, I can retrieve all events with get() in a array, and watch() all of them as well:

[image: All events]

The Array (app.js:219) represents get() and each event (app.js:180) has been watched all over again, so there is 269 of them. Once the latest event is the latest watched (obviously), it is retrieved with #events successfully.

But, with so much events, it gets messy. I was wondering if i could filter with some parameter to reduce the number of events returned.

I appreciate the attention!

Comment: It can be solved if you store your state in a cookie or local storage in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I did that (localStorage). The problem with that is: if someone access the dapp from other machine, won't retrieve any transactionHash at first, and then will only retrieve transactionHashs generated while his/her dapp is open.

Comment: Actually, I found a way to retrieve the last transactionHash uniting .watch() and get(). I will update the question. 

I still curious about filtering the parameters, anyway.

Comment: Geth and Parity follow web3 api specs and have a limited functionality to filter events, if it is within a block range and filter by indexed paramaters. As alternative you can store in your contract the last block a user generated an event. When your dapp starts query the user last block, and with that can adjust the events block range.